# How can I send the parameter with the firestore get method?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My project is creating a website using firebase, but it is using the internal authen micro service instead of Firebase authen.
Every time the user logs in, the internal authen service will generate a token (I call it `client_id`), and send it to the client.
This token is also stored in the user collection.
Please help me how to write rule for the user via this `client_id`.
If it is write role, I can send the client_id via mothod `update`, `delete`, `create` and get it out by
`request.resource.data.cliend_id` and check it.
But if it is read role, I don't have any way to send to the client_id via the get method to authenticate users
I even thought of replacing all the get methods with the update methods to pass the client_id 
But the response of the update method is just the update_time, not the object I updated

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: @AlekseyRazbakov maybe because I conveyed so confusing so you misunderstood. I've already built a website that uses customToken to log in via Line, so I still need to use Firebase Auth to gen idtoken. 
But this time I did not use Firebase Auth to gen idtoken, and the internal authen system will gen token (it is client_id) and return it to the client, and this token is also stored in the user collection.

Comment: If there is no other way, I have to go back to using firebase authen
but I am trying to find a solution to save effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase RTDB & Firestore Rules uses their own auth only. In every request that firebase client library sends uid **along with jwt token and other security parameters**. These are fundamental to firebase's working and thus can't be replaced.

As Aleksey mentioned, you can try custom auth. It is specifically tailored for such use cases only.

Comment: As i thought there is no other way to authenticate users other than using firebase authen
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to provide extra data to security rules for the purpose of limiting read operations. That would not be secure at all, because a client could simply fake whatever they want in the query.

You can only use information provided by Firebase Auth available in [request.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), the data in the document itself in [resource.data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data), or the [contents of other documents using get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).  If you want to attach additional data to the user account, consider using [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).